# Thunderbird not checking mail automatically

Tags: email, windows-7, thunderbird

I'm using Thunderbird 15.0.1 Windows 7 x64. I figured out the [issue](https://getsatisfaction.com/mozilla_messaging/topics/thunderbird_not_checking_mail_automatically-1darp0?rfm=1) few updates ego.
Once I tried to turn off all add-ons, but its not helps.

I have only one POP e-mail account (and it is default), in "Server" settings checked box for "Check for new mail every 5 minutes", "Automatically download new messages", "Leave message on server", "For at most 14 days", "Until I delete them".

How to fix it?

Comment: Do you have some way of knowing whether this has to do with the server side of things. Is this your own email? If so, who is hosting it?

Comment: this is MS Exchange corporative email. But before few Thundebird updates everything was ok. So I suppose its nothing wrong with the server.

Comment: Just to clarify some things. You have no add-ons or themes correct?

Comment: I do not have themes but I do have add-ons. So once I disabled all of them and nothing changed.

Comment: What a second. "But before few Thunderbird updates everything was ok"
You mean you only had this problem when Thunderbird updated?

Comment: Yes, that’s right.

Comment: Seems like a problem with Thunderbird itself, a bug or something. I don't believe there is anything users can do. You might want to file a bug. See below:
http://email.about.com/od/mozillathunderbirdtips/qt/et_report_bug.htm

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. I think it occurred with the TB 13.0. I was told by the hosting provider, that this is because of some changes in TB's new version, and they gonna set their servers to work with the changes, soon. Yet, there is still no solution. So I had to switch off all those options, except "Leave on server", leaving the subsequent options unchecked. And it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Icedove 31.6.0 (Thunderbird fork). I could resolve this by removing the account which was initially created by the `Mail Account Setup` wizard and then using the `Account Settings` panel which can be accessed via `Menu > Preferences > Account Settings`. Strange, but it worked with the exact same settings used before.